# Moving to a different team, but having second thoughts

Tags: software-industry

I work as a software engineer. I think I was not that happy with the current work and the team's work culture, it all went down-hill when I was called to work on something on a Friday evening, I spent sometime on Saturday late night and also worked on Sunday the whole day.

To me it felt like he just cares about the project milestone and nothing about other people's personal boundaries, he kinda expects people to work late night and he appreciates them for that thus making a toxic workplace.

So I reached out to other managers and had a normal convo and was able to get an offer, I liked the manager and the way he made me feel,  I informed the old manager that I'm looking for a change and he didn't take it lightly

Later, my old manager's manager called and had a chat, the reason I gave was just the working hours are too much and that the pace of the project was aggressive. He acknowledged the issues and told things will get better soon

Comment: Yes. It's normal to take time off without approvals. Only vacation days needs to be approved

Comment: What? You didn't even leave the company. Why is the manager's manager being involved? There's something really weird going on.

Comment: Other comments you say your current manager is a liar. I would recommend including that as well as the circumstance that illustrates his dishonesty in your question as it helps shape the answers.

Answer (score 8):

> **he just cares** about the project milestone and **nothing about other people's personal boundaries**, he kinda expects people to work late night and he appreciates them for that thus **making a toxic workplace**.

and

> I informed the old manager that I will be leaving to a new team and he didn't take it lightly, **he was furious**

additionally,

> my old manager's manager called and had a chat... and asked me to reconsider.

So your old boss is far from being nice, and additionally does not care to say "Sorry, please come back" personally. I guess that if you return, nothing will change, the boss will be the same, regardless of what the boss's boss talks.

My opinion is that you need to create some space between you and toxic people, whoever they are. Especially, if you have good opportunities to do so (even though sometimes it is difficult).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you have over-reacted to a minor thing. The manager obviously has a warped mentality and is clearly running a sweatshop.

It would have been better for you to have asked for the time off rather than simply announcing it, but whatever judgment led to that has to be put into the context of being tired from overwork and dealing with an obviously unreasonable manager in general, and it may have been an attempt to finally impose some boundaries.

I reach that conclusion given that the manager didn't make prior arrangements for your time off in lieu despite calling you to work in the evening, and when you announced time off in lieu he instructed you to take it as leave (rather than, for example, merely objecting to the inconvenient timing of the lieu day).

You may find that any attempt now to apologise is just a cynical response to the fact that he knows he's exceeded your breaking point, having only intended to push you to the precipice (and not beyond) - it probably doesn't reflect a real reorientation of perspective on what kind of working hours are reasonable.

Comment: My manager did mention if we work on weekends, we can take comp-off in front of a wider audience, so it looked normal to ask for it. Him denying the comp-off and not crediting my effort for time spent on the weekends in front of the wider audience just made me look bad...

Comment: @prabs, so what you're saying is that he's a liar?

Comment: Yup. He just changes things on the fly as it suits him. I heard him say that in a wider audience plus heard him say that in a 1:1.

Answer (score 1):

A culture of regular overtime would be bad.  You clearly don't like this and it is very unlikely to change significantly so it is sensible for you to move.

However, your behaviour following overtime and the way you went about arranging the move have room for improvement.  Things went very wrong when your manager ended up annoyed with you after you gave up your weekend to help out.  The way you went about moving team could have been improved too.  If you are moving to a new team, this would be a good time for some introspection and a softening of your approach.

Unilaterally announcing that you were taking a day of in lieu of weekend work was unprofessional.  You should have checked whether a policy of compensating overtime exists first.  If one existed, it'd still likely have required negotiation with your manager to find a mutually acceptable day, just as with any other request for a planned absence.  If one didn't exist, a gentler request - "I'm struggling after working all weekend, can I take today to help recover please?" - would have been more likely to succeed.  In the worst case, you at least wouldn't have annoyed your boss so much that they no longer looked favourably on you having worked the weekend.  You owe your current manager a small amount of gratitude here - if they were really as hard-nosed as you feel he could have taken formal action against you for this unauthorised absence.

The way you approached the team move will likely also have been perceived as rude.  It'd be polite to have informed your boss sooner that you were considering an internal transfer.  If only to avoid them being caught out when another department gets in touch for a reference.

Comment: Are you OP's boss? Where is working unpaid Saturdays and Sundays good work culture or good team culture?

Comment: I agree the culture is horrible and that the OP should move team.  If you can point me to where I seemed to be supporting the culture, I'll reword.  I was just trying to say that the OP has responded poorly to this challenging environment.  Announcing that you have awarded yourself extra days off and are taking them without consultation will annoy most (good or bad) bosses.

Comment: The way I read it, each statement of your answer tells that OP overreacted and had inappropriate behavior. If you did not intend to say that, then maybe you re-word your statements somehow. Just saying.

Comment: One way to re-write the first sentence (it might not be your intention): "You clearly don't like the *bad* culture in the team." The word *bad* underlines your opinion on the state of things.

Comment: Thanks.  I've tried to reword to be clearer that the team culture is poor but that the OP responded to this a bit petulantly.  While they can't control the culture of their team, they can try to deal with adversity better in future.

Comment: I don't think I suggested any of the cases you list were wrong - my comments were about planned absence.  I'd count taking a day in lieu as a planned absence that should be agreed in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> He acknowledged the issues and told things will get better in 2-3 months

Now, it depends on the level of understanding and trust you have in your former manager. I've been told that more than once ("*be patient, things will improve...*"), with mixed results:

1. Mr Toxic was effectively moving 2-3 months later. New manager, different story.
2. Mr Toxic was still there, nothing had changed. I had been fooled, I'd move.

At this time, your current manager cares *only* about deadlines and results, people don't even come close second to that. Will that improve in a close future? Because of him, no way.

What you need to know is a little more about the future. But managers can't always disclose companies' strategies. When I knew I could ask my former boss about the future, I'd be as diplomatic as possible (didn't ask in a straightforward way if Mr Toxic would be (re)moved). My advice would be to discuss things by silently implying what you expect. Don't say: "*I can't stand that guy, I won't be able to survive and suffer this toxic behaviour again and again*. Talk about the difficulties without turning them into a useless rant: "*I'm pretty sure I can help and stay for a couple of months, but future days need to be brighter than now by then. With him around, I doubt...*".
If your manager is smart, he'll get the hint, and might give you something interesting to chew on in return.

IMO, you didn't overreact, but acting in a softer manner is always good. Choice for the future is still up to you though.

Answer (score 0):

### No

You did not overreact. I think you made a good choice (do you have the same pay?).. if so then h.. yeas you made the right call.

> things will get better in 2-3 months

And we will have self driving cars in the next 1-2 years.

Notice how I am not holding my breath? for either?

It is possible that the work culture is going to change in the next 2-3 months... But, what if it doesn't. Will you be able to return back to the place you are now which has a "better work culture and manager" even if the domain is not as "exciting"? Answer: you probably won't be able to. Do you want to spend the next 2-3 months (assuming there really is a change) working hard with barely any recognition, but berated if you slow down to keep your own sanity?

A thing to remember is that as far as any company is concerend... you are replaceable. THey might moan and groan about how irreplaceable you are. But if you were to kick the bucket tomorrow, the company would be over it the day after.

Don't buy into bad work culture because your work is "exciting." Somewhat less exciting work + more time in the day/weekend for self care is worth so much more... You only have one life, and I can guarantee you that looking back you will never think "I should have spent more time in the office."

My response to your old manager's manager would be.

"Thank you for letting me know that things will get better over there in the next 2-3 months, but I have to decline your offer."

Wait 2-3 months, I guarantee you that things will not have gotten better over there.